# Commands not found missing in terminal on my Mac?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, command-line, terminal

My system was fine, but today, after installing MySQL server, I can't use the terminal to program my Rails application.

When I open a terminal session, I see:

```
Last login: Sun Dec  8 13:31:06 on console
-bash: [: missing `]'
-bash: rt: command not found
```

I tried searching for this error but can't find a solution.

I am running Mac 10.7 OS X.

No commands pertaining to Ruby on Rails are found.

I built an application and installed Rails, but when I run a Rails command I get:

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

How do I fix this?

My bashrc file contains only one line:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

My bash profile contains following:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
[ [-s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
rt PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

I checked history and this is what I ran

```
vi .bash_profile
vi .bash_profile
user@computer:$ mysql -u root
mysql -u root
vi .bash_profile
mysql -u root
/usr/local/mysql-5.6.15-osx10.7-x86_64/bin/mysqld_safe ; exit;
mysql
```

What else can I show to help with this problem?

Comment: You really haven't given us enough information to deal with this. What commands did you run prior to the problem happening? Also, append the output of `gem env` to your question.

Comment: Also, it looks like your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` is messed up if you're getting that error when you open your terminal. I suspect the PATH variable is incorrect.

Comment: i ran commands vi .bash_profile  then export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin   then type “:wq”   following one tutorial on the web installing mysql.

Comment: i suspect path is messed up,  how do i fix it?

Comment: I don't know; You haven't showed us anything relating to it. Think maybe that would help?

Comment: I updated some info, what can i show you more?

Comment: i ran vi .bash_profile during installing mysql

Comment: Could the extra space in `[ [-s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]]` be a problem? Could you try to remove it?

Comment: The bashrc line `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin` is wrong. RVM has to be first in the path. Read the [installation page](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) completely to understand what and why. The line initializing RVM shouldn't be `[ [`, it needs to be `[[`. That isn't how RVM added it to the file so you have to have modified it. Once you fix those things, quit Terminal and then reopen a shell window, then run `rvm info` and past that information into your question also.

Comment: I suspect that `rt PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin` is really supposed to be `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin` but you pasted that into vi's command-line which ignored `exp`, saw `o`, and opened a new line and typed the rest of the line into the file.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.bash_profile` is messed up.  Modify what looks like this:

```
[ [-s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function* 
rt PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

To look like this:

```
[[-s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

As @TinMan pointed out, you'll want to remove the `export PATH` line from your `.bashrc` file.

Comment: The OPs PATH will still have problems because `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (although I'm running Ubuntu). When I opened a new terminal and navigated to my project root, I was surprised to find that Rails was not recognized as a program. I checked the version of Ruby and noted that there was a discrepancy between the two terminals I had open. When I tried to switch Ruby versions with RVM, I was told

```
You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
```

so I ran `/bin/bash --login`. Then, I was able to switch to Ruby 2.1.1 with `RVM use ruby-2.1.1` and all my rails commands worked again.

Basically what happened is that RVM only installs gems locally for each Ruby verison. Unless you select the version of Ruby that you were using when you installed the gem, you won't be able to use the gem unless you reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

I came to this page after receiving this error with a slightly different cause. While the CDub's answer is directly applicable to OP's question, I would generally recommend users of Mac OS X Terminal who have this error to do the following:

- Open ~/.bash_profile in a text editor.
- Look for any instances of "rt" at the beginning of a line.
- Change all instances to "export".

It looks like some packages out there are writing a command into ~/.bash_profile that Mac OS X does not like, and we need to manually correct this.

For reference, I am on OS 10.10.2.